# Boton funcione con enter y vacie formulario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, login

Necesito saber como hacer que los dos botones que tengo en 2 formularios diferentes al precionar enter ejecute la funcion y vacie los datos que estan en los input.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.formulario').animate({
        height: "toggle",
        'padding-top': 'toggle',
        'padding-bottom': 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, "slow");
});

var users = [];
var names = [];
var lnames = [];
var passs = [];
var cuentas = [users,names,lnames,passs];


users.push("admin");
names.push("Administrador");
lnames.push("principal");
passs.push("12345")


function registro(){
    users.push(document.getElementById('user').value);
    names.push(document.getElementById('name').value);
    lnames.push(document.getElementById('lname').value);
    passs.push(document.getElementById('pass').value);
}


var userlog;
var passlog;
function login(){
    userlog = document.getElementById('userlogin').value;
    passlog = document.getElementById('passlogin').value;
    if(userlog === cuentas[0][0] && passlog === cuentas[3][0]){
        alert("Bienvenido " + cuentas[1][0]);
    }else{
        if(users.length < 2){
            alert("ESTE USUARIO NO ESTA REGISTRADO");
            alert("PRUEBE A REGISTRARSE");
        }else{
            var i = 1;
            while(i < users.length + 1){
                    if(userlog === cuentas[0][i] && passlog === cuentas[3][i]){
                        alert("Bienvenido " + cuentas[1][i] + " " + cuentas[2][i]);
                        break;
                    }else if(userlog != cuentas[0][i] && passlog != cuentas[3][i]){
                        alert("USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTOS");
                        alert("REVISE LA INFORMACION INGRESADA");
                        break;
                    }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: url(gymbg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.contenedor-form{
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin:  48px auto;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius:  5px;
}

.contenedor-form .toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-top: 2px solid darkred;
    border-bottom: 2px solid darkred;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contenedor-form .toggle span {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.contenedor-form .toggle:hover{
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(78, 78, 78);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(78, 78, 78);
}

.contenedor-form h2 {
    margin: 0 0 28px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1px;
}

.contenedor-form input[type="text"],
.contenedor-form input[type="password"],
.contenedor-form input[type="email"]{
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0,0, .5);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid darkred;;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.contenedor-form input[type="text"]:focus,
.contenedor-form input[type="password"]:focus,
.contenedor-form input[type="email"]:focus{
    border-bottom:  4px solid rgb(78, 78, 78);
}

.contenedor-form button{
    background: darkred;;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: monospace;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.contenedor-form input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background: rgba(78,78,78,0.7);
}

.contenedor-form .reset-password{
    background: rgba(78,78,78,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.contenedor-form .reset-password a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.contenedor-form .formulario{
    padding: 40px;
    display: none;
}
 .contenedor-form .formulario:nth-child(2){
     display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleslogin.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../src general/zonalogo.ico"/>
    <title>The Zone GYM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article class="login">
    <div class="contenedor-form">
        <div class="toggle">
            <span>LOGIN</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="formulario">
            <h2> Registrate </h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario"  id="user" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombres"  id="name" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" id="lname" required >
                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="pass" required >
                <button onclick="registro()">Registrarse</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </br>
            <div class="formulario">
                <h2> Login </h2>
                <form action="#">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" id="userlogin" required>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="passlogin" required>
                    <button onclick="login()" id="botonlog">Iniciar Sesion</button>
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="reset-password">
                <a href="#">Olvide mi contraseña</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jslogin.js"></script>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

put

Answer (score 1):

Al darle clic en la función se tiene que ejecutar la función.
Lo único que tienes que hacer es hacer una función como por ejemplo:

```
function clearInputs() {
document.querySelector('input').value = '';
}

function login(){
    userlog = document.getElementById('userlogin').value;
    passlog = document.getElementById('passlogin').value;
    if(userlog === cuentas[0][0] && passlog === cuentas[3][0]){
        alert("Bienvenido " + cuentas[1][0]);
    }else{
        if(users.length < 2){
            alert("ESTE USUARIO NO ESTA REGISTRADO");
            alert("PRUEBE A REGISTRARSE");
        }else{
            var i = 1;
            while(i < users.length + 1){
                    if(userlog === cuentas[0][i] && passlog === cuentas[3][i]){
                        alert("Bienvenido " + cuentas[1][i] + " " + cuentas[2][i]);
                        break;
                    }else if(userlog != cuentas[0][i] && passlog != cuentas[3][i]){
                        alert("USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTOS");
                        alert("REVISE LA INFORMACION INGRESADA");
                        break;
                    }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
 clearInputs();
}
```

Lo mismo en el registro, simplemente le pones al final que luego de ejecutar eso los deje vacíos, no afectará en nada, sólo en los inputs.
Te puede quedar más fácil a entenderlo con los puntos de interrupción o los Debugger, para que veas el proceso exacto que hace tú proyecto.
Saludos!